# What is the correct solution for mocking fluent interface in my case?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, mstest

I have fluent interface `IReceiver` that I mock. Each method of the interface just adds a request to collection and when `Get` is called it returns values for the `requests`.

Because only the last setup wins I always get `new List<int>{22}` as the result whenever `AddRequest1().Get()` or `AddRequest2().Get()` is called.
As a workaround I came up with the solution below that worked for me.

Is there any other more elegant solution or I just should write some extension that will take `receiverMock.Setup(_ => _.AddRequest1().Get()).Returns(new List<int>{11})` as expression, build a new mock and return the new mock?

**Solution**

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test1()
{
   var receiverMock = new Mock<IReceiver>();
   
   var mock1 = new Mock<IReceiver>();
   mock1.Setup(_ => _.Get()).Returns(new List<int>{11});
   receiverMock.Setup(_ => _.AddRequest1()).Returns(mock1);

   var mock2 = new Mock<IReceiver>();
   mock2.Setup(_ => _.Get()).Returns(new List<int>{22});
   receiverMock.Setup(_ => _.AddRequest2()).Returns(mock2);

   var prog = new Program(receiverMock.Object);
   ...
}
```

**Code**

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test1()
{
   var receiverMock = new Mock<IReceiver>();
   receiverMock.Setup(_ => _.AddRequest1().Get()).Returns(new List<int>{11});
   receiverMock.Setup(_ => _.AddRequest2().Get()).Returns(new List<int>{22});

   var prog = new Program(receiverMock.Object);
   ...
}

public interface IReceiver
{
    IReceiver AddRequest1();
    IReceiver AddRequest2();
    IReceiver AddRequest3();    
    List<int> Get();
}

public class Receiver: IReceiver
{
    List<Request> _requests;
    public IReceiver AddRequest1()
    {
        _requests.Add("item1");
        return this;
    }

    public IReceiver AddRequest2()
    {
        _requests.Add("item2");
        return this;
    }

    public IReceiver AddRequest3()
    {
        _requests.Add("item3");
        return this;
    }
 
    public List<int> Get()
    {
       List<int> results;
       // get values for items in _requests
       return results; 
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by _more elegant_? Do you have an idea/some pseudo-code in your mind?

Comment: @mu88, I included my solution in the post and explained what probably be a more elegant solution. But, I'd like to hear if there is a better way.

Comment: Ah okay then I misunderstood you, sry  your proposed solution with the helper method/extension seems good to me

Comment: @theateist Sorry, but could you please fix your code sample first? Your `Setup` calls are not compiling because `AddRequestN` anticipates a `string` parameter. Your `Receiver` class does not compile because the `Receiver` class does not implement `IReceiver` interface....

Comment: @PeterCsala, I've updated my post. It was easier just to remove `string itemName" argument for the argument sake

Comment: What do you want to test? What scenarios do you want to cover with tests?

Comment: I use it as `receiver.AddRequest1().Get()` or `receiver.AddRequest1().AddRequest2().AddRequest3().Get()` and etc

Comment: Since you try to mock the IReceiver, you are testing not the Receiver implementation. So, I am asking again what do you want to test?